# is possible to solve inactive account exchange in redemption file .pst

Tags: outlook-redemption

AddressEntry.Name is a name account inactive into exchange

can not  resolve:
oSession.AddressBook.ResolveName(addressEntry.Name)

It is posible!

Comment: We're not customer support, this is off-topic.

Comment: It is only question. Thank you

Comment: Let me be a bit more clear. We are not here to troubleshoot your problems. You must provide all the code, and a clear description of what problem you are having. You have none of that right now, so your question is off-topic.

Comment: Are you trying to convert an EX type address to SMTP? Where does that recipient come from? A message recipients' table?

Comment: yes!! but have the next problem.                                                      Error in AddrBook.ResolveName: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND and       Error in AddrBook.ResolveName: MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIP

Comment: it are account inactive inside exchange!! Howto can get address?

Answer (score 0):

I reading a file pst that have account exchange  inactive  into sender. Is possible resolver or convert to smtp with redemption